# FFMPEG: AAC Number of bands exceeds limit

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I am using the FFMPEG C API to decode the audio in an MP4 file.

My code works when decoding an OGG or MP3 file, but fails on the first frame of AAC audio in an MP4

I get this error from

```
avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, packet)

[aac @ 0x7f80eb9e3a00] Number of bands (31) exceeds limit (5)
```

What is the "number of bands" and how do I increase it?  What does this message really mean?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Hello Lord, My code is in Scala and calls the java-cpp-presets wrapper for FFMEG.  It also involves Custom I/IO from data in a Java Buffer.  This is a long way of saying the whole code is big and might cause more questions than it answers.  Which part of the code do you need to see?  Is this problem perhaps part of the creation of the codec or format?

Comment: A self-contained code that is sufficient to reproduce the error would be useful.